# Function to populate created table using trigger on another table is not inserting any data

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a project for school. They gave us a sample database in postgresql and we have to have a detailed table (which is a combination of multiple fields from joining two tables) and a summary table (which is populated using fields of your choice from the detailed table). I am using a trigger on the detail table to insert values from the detailed table into the summary table, and in this function I have it so that it concatenates two of the data fields from the detail table and concatenates them in the summary table. however whenever viewing the table after the function, it concatenated the fields but didn't include the new field name. It just moved over the fields into one column and kept the same column name, and deleted a column from my table.

-- Code for my function

```
Create or Replace Function refresh_summary_table ()
Returns Trigger
language plpgsql
As
$$
Begin
    Delete From summary_data_table;
    Insert Into summary_data_table (
        SELECT customer_id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name, email, active
        FROM detailed_data_table
        WHERE active = '0'
        GROUP BY customer_id, full_name, email, active
        ORDER BY customer_id DESC
        LIMIT 100
    );
    RETURN NEW;
End;
$$
```

-- Creating the Trigger

```
Create or Replace Trigger summary_refresh
After Insert ON detailed_data_table
For Each STATEMENT
Execute Procedure refresh_summary_table();
```

-- After viewing the table after running these. This is the output I get

```
"customer_id"   "first_name"          "last_name"                   "email"         "active"
592 "Terrance Roush"    "terrance.roush@sakilacustomer.org"   "0"            [null]
558 "Jimmie Eggleston"  "jimmie.eggleston@sakilacustomer.org"     "0"            [null]
534 "Christian Jung"    "christian.jung@sakilacustomer.org"   "0"            [null]
510 "Ben Easter"            "ben.easter@sakilacustomer.org"           "0"            [null]
482 "Maurice Crawley"   "maurice.crawley@sakilacustomer.org"      "0"            [null]
446 "Theodore Culp"         "theodore.culp@sakilacustomer.org"    "0"            [null]
406 "Nathan Runyon"         "nathan.runyon@sakilacustomer.org"    "0"            [null]
368 "Harry Arce"            "harry.arce@sakilacustomer.org"       "0"            [null]
```

I was expecting the first_name and last_name columns to merge the data into a column called full_name. If i highlight and only run the part of the insert statement in my function where i do the concatenation. The output is as expected.

Comment: You are making a fundamental mistake if you try to recalculate the *whole* `summary_data_table`. You should write a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger that only updates the one line in `summary_data_table` that belongs to the row at hand. Besides, I see no summary anywhere.

Comment: You're saying the trigger does the Wrong Thing, as perhaps previous revs of your code did. And that an interactive SELECT looks good now. What have you done to convince yourself that the `refresh_summary_table` running behind the scenes is the same version as the (good) SELECT you run interactively? Are you _sure_ you don't have a leftover stale version of the trigger code running, when you were hoping that a newer revision would run instead? (Oh and yeah, the remark about fundamental mistake is spot on -- a BG trigger should be going for incremental updates. Do reports in the foreground.)